# require checkbox selection php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am having what seems to be a very easy issue to resolve in my mind. I have an html form with checkbox groups and i want to be able to enforce a selection of checkboxes. At this point I just want to write an error that will come up with echo if none of the checkboxes are selected from a group. I am sending the checkbox array through a mysql query and when nothing is selected I'm getting an empty page. My confusion is how to write the PHP code to return an error. I've tried

```
if (empty($_GET){
echo "ERROR" ;}
```

and

```
if (empty($color)){
echo "ERROR" ;}
```

Maybe I'm just brain dead but this seems like it should work. Here is my html code that is currently working for the checkboxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Black">Black
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Blue">Blue
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Brown">Brown
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Green">Green 
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Grey">Grey
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Orange">Orange 
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Pink">Pink
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Purple">Purple
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Red">Red
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Teal">Teal
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="White">White
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Yellow">Yellow
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pattcat[]" value="Home Decor">Home Decor
<input type="checkbox" name="pattcat[]" value="Children">Children
<input type="checkbox" name="pattcat[]" value="Tops Women">Tops Women
<input type="checkbox" name="pattcat[]" value="Accessories">Accessories
<input type="checkbox" name="pattcat[]" value="Lace">Lace
<input type="checkbox" name="pattcat[]" value="Tops Men">Tops Men
<br>
```

Comment: Show your HTML for the checkboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `if( empty($_GET['color']))`? Just because it's an array doesn't mean it's any different to a normal GET variable.

Also, make sure the form method is GET, rather than POST.

Comment: Thank you! This works best because I can use a combination of ['color']['pattcat'] for the Error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's not a POST

```
if (empty($_GET["color"]){
    echo "ERROR" ;
}
```

`$GET`is hash keyed by the form element's name (`color`). When the name ends with `[]`, it becomes an array. For checkboxes, only checked ones are sent.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is something like this...

```
if (empty($_POST["color"]) {
    echo "ERROR" ;
}
```

But why waste the user's valuable time by making them submit to find out their mistake? Why not use some nice JavaScript (jQuery or other) to only allow them to submit the form once it's been completed to your satisfaction? You can even disable the 'submit' button until they do, or present concise errors when they fail to fill out enough information.

Comment: You need both, your comment about jQuery assumes something the OP is not said (that there is no client side check)